# Python function that can be used to find the number of integers in a list

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python, I am looking for a function that can tell me the number of integers in a given list. For example:

```
list = [1, 2, 4.5, 6, 8.3, 9]
print(int_num(list))
```

output

```
4
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to request a function. Here you present your function which does not work as expected.

Comment: @Klaus No, not all questions need to be debugging questions. How-to questions are perfectly fine. E.g. [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea That's not a how-to question.

Comment: @Klaus What do you mean? It doesn't literally say "how to", but you could easily rephrase it as "How to count the occurrences of a list item?"

Comment: @wjandrea Well, following that logic, any "question" trying to outsource homework is also a how-to question. Or in other words: the question here is missing any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. The problem with do my homework questions is that they aren't generally applicable to multiple situations or future visitors. A simple task such as this question can be.

Comment: @duckboycool Exactly. See for example this Meta discussion: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Answer (score -1):

```
def isInt(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
ls = [1,2,4.5,6,8.3,9] 

# Note filter function is used to filter out elements that do not satisy the function in our case it is isInt 
# filter function gives a filter object cast it to a list
filtered = list(filter(isInt, ls))
print(filtered)
print(len(filtered))
```

Comment: You wrote a whole function to wrap a simple built-in function, and included a control structure to wrap the return value of the call. Seriously?

Comment: Building a new list is unnecessary. You can do `sum(isinstance(x, int) for x in ls)`, since `True` will be coerced to `1` and `False` to `0`.

Comment: But FWIW, the if-statement is also unnecessary. Instead, `return isinstance(x, int)`

Comment: Also, `filter` is not a function, and it returns a `filter` object, not a list.

Comment: Thanks but let it be what is is for explicitness.

Answer (score -2):

There is already a built-in function `len()`, that, if required, can be wrapped in your own custom function

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(len(list))
```